# Erro ao ler um arquivo .xls

Tags: python

Tenho alguns arquivos para ler em Python, estou usando a seguinte estrutura:

> df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t')

E isso gerou o seguinte erro:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 9: unexpected end of data

Procurando pela internet, eu adicionei um engine='python' (df = pd.read_csv(path, engine='python', sep='\t')) e ele leu normalmente, achei que os meus problemas haviam acabado, mas quando fui ler os outros arquivos, aconteceu o seguinte erro:

Utilizar encoding = 'ISO-8859-1' também resolveu no primeiro caso, mas nos outros arquivos ficou o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> pandas.errors.ParserError: NULL byte detected. This byte cannot be processed in Python's native csv library at the moment, so please pass in engine='c' instead

Visualmente, ambos os arquivos são iguais, mesmo tipo de dados, mesmo tamanho praticamente, mesma extensão. Alguém sabe o pq dessa incompatibilidade?

Answer (score 2):

Se você tem um arquivo "XLS" com no título da questão, ele não vai poder ser lido com funções para ler arquivos "CSV". São arquivos fundamentalmente diferentes. (E arquivos CSV normalmente não vão ter bytes "\x00" dentro - por isso acho mesmo que seja um arquivo Excel).

Se for um arquivo `.xlsx`, o Pandas tem a função `read_excel` que você pode usar. Se for uma planilha legada ".xls", suas opções serão instalar uma outra biblioteca Python para acessar os dados, e depois converte-los para um dataframe, ou abrir no Excel e salvar em outro formato.